# Ajax query uncaught reference

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm struggling to call an AJAX query. I looked at some hints on stackoverflow and ensured that the jquery is referenced before my script is called. I am still getting this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". It could be that I am a little bit confused by this '$'. Do you have some hints for me what I should be looking at ? Could it be that the jquery version is too old to make it work?

My HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Run demo mode</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/date_time.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/demo_mode.js"></script> <!--new-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle_demo.css?rnd=999" />
  <body onload="startTimer(); ">
    <div id="logo" style="position:absolute; width:50%; height:50%;">
      <a href="home.html">
        <img src="assets/icons/logo.png" alt ="" style="width:100px;height:72px;">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="date"></div>        
    <div id="buttons">
  <table class="buttons_table">
      <td height="200"><button id="button_yes" class="button_yes" onclick="confirmDemoMode()">Oui</button></td>
      <td><button id="button_no" class="button_no" onclick="backtoInitPage()">Annuler</button></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My Script (demo_mode.js) :

```
function backtoInitPage()
{
    window.location.href='home.html'
}

function confirmDemoMode()
{
    sendSMS('This is a SMS', '41773216699');
}

function sendSMS(pSmsMessage, pNumber)
{
    var args = '';
    $.ajax({      // <------- This is according to the console, where the problem pops up ?
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/interface_php_ajax_sms.php",
    data : {sms_message: pSmsMessage, 
    msisdn: pNumber
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(code_html, statut){ // success est toujours en place, bien sûr !
    },
    error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){
    },
    complete : function(resultat, statut){
    }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is being loaded? What does the network tab of your console show?

Comment: You're right, I cannot find the jquery  I thought naively that it would be sufficient to have it referenced in the header ...:( <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: That should normally be all you need.

Comment: Does it mean that I am missing something in my js file ?

Comment: remove the point before the slash in your script tag <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>